# What is Meshroom cameraSensor.db entry for Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 (newly available Jan 2023)?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am building a camera array for photogrammetry using the Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3 that is newly available in my area in January 2023. I use [Meshroom](https://alicevision.org/) for photogrammetry and it has a database with camera sensor information. I'll need to add a new line for this new camera!

The cameraSensors.db file from the newest Meshroom-2021.1.0 contains these lines for older Raspberry Pi cameras:

RaspberryPi;RP_imx219;3.6736;devicespecifications

RaspberryPi;RP_imx477;6.287;devicespecifications

RaspberryPi;RP_OV5647;3.6288;devicespecifications

Could someone please tell me what the line should read for the [Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#hardware-specification) available in early 2023? My thought from the camera [specs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/accessories/camera.html#hardware-specification) is immediately below, but I found that it didn't work. I still got the "Camera Intrinsics: Unknown" warning.

RaspberryPi;RP_imx708;6.45;devicespecifications

Here is the Meshroom warning when I tried to use images from the RP V3 camera
[image: intrinsics unknown for RP V3 cam]

I tried other entries based on the text in the warning, but had no luck.
Can anyone help get this entry correct for the Meshroom cameraSensors.db text file?

Thank you, DS

Comment: What other entries did you try? Which troubleshooting steps [from the manual](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom/wiki/Add-Camera-to-database) did you try?

Comment: Hello, I used exiftool-12.61 to examine the metadata from a jpg image taken with the RPi Camera Module V3. I include that example image metadata below. From that metadata, I adjusted the Meshroom cameraSensors.db file to reflect the Make and Model as follows: 'Raspberry Pi;/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx708@1a;6.45;devicespecifications'.

Comment: From the Meshroom manual (at the link you provided), they do make a suggestion that I could strip the rest of the metadata to avoid the issue "Meshroom asks to add camera info to database, even if it already exists." I will have to learn how to do that if I need to go that route. Thank you for your suggestions. Here is a link to the metadata from a single image. TS  [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/elwhjdbt0pt9hus/example_RPi_CamModV3_metadata.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation of Meshroom](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom/wiki) it says on the page on [adding a camera](https://github.com/alicevision/meshroom/wiki/Add-Camera-to-database):

> You can add your own Camera and Sensor by adding a new line to the camerasensor.db located in ..\Meshroom-2018.1.0\aliceVision\share\aliceVision\ (you can use any text editor). Before editing the database, close Meshroom. Edit and save the edited file.
>
> The format is:
>
> ```
> CameraMaker;CameraModel;SensorWidth(mm);source
> ```

As the sensor is indeed 6.45 mm wide (according to the specs) your suggestion seems correct:

```
RaspberryPi;RP_imx708;6.45;devicespecifications
```

Comment: Thank you Saaru. Unfortunately when I tried Meshroom with photos from the Raspberry Pi Camera Module Version 3, it did not recognize the images with the edit to the cameraSensors.dB we had discussed above. I have edited my original post to include the warning message from Meshroom. Best regards, TS